# component 'DEPARTMENT_ID' must be declared PLSQL

Tags: database, plsql

I have the following code.

```
DECLARE 
    TYPE t_dep IS TABLE OF DEPARTMENTS%ROWTYPE
    INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;
    v_dep t_dep;
BEGIN
    FOR dep_rec IN
        (SELECT department_name, location_id FROM Departments
         ORDER BY department_id ASC)
    LOOP
        v_dep(dep_rec.department_id) := dep_rec;
    END LOOP;
END;
```

And I get this error:

```
Error report -
ORA-06550: line 10, column 23:
PLS-00302: component 'DEPARTMENT_ID' must be declared
ORA-06550: line 10, column 9:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:
```

This is the departments table.
[image: Departments Table]

Here is my task:

*Write an anonymous PL/SQL block that declares and populates an INDEX BY table of records containing
department data. The table of records should use the departmentid as a primary key, and each element should
contain department name and location id. The data should be stored in the INDEX BY table of records in ascending
sequence of departmentid. The block should not display any output.*

How can I deal with this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create your loop over this implict cursor

```
SELECT department_name, location_id
FROM Departments
ORDER BY department_id ASC
```

you say that you are only interested in the columns `department_name, location_id`.

If you even need ID, you have to add it to the select list:

```
SELECT department_name, location_id, department_id
```

Also, your structure is defined as

```
TABLE OF DEPARTMENTS%ROWTYPE
```

so you need all the coumns of the table, in the right order, to populate it: you need  `manager_id` too.

Another point: if you define a structure as `INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER`, you have to use a binary integer to index it; are you sure `department_id` is a binary index?

Comment: Yeah, I added department_id and manager_id and that worked. But the task says: each element should contain department name and location id. Thanks for the response!

Answer (score 1):

`DEP_REC` contains `department_name` and `location_id`, while you're using `department_id` in this statement:

```
v_dep(dep_rec.department_id) := dep_rec;
              -------------
```

As it doesn't exist, your code fails.

How to fix it? Include `department_id` into cursor `FOR` loop's `SELECT` statement.

Also, as `DEPARTMENTS` table contains 4 columns, you'll have to select them all in order to make it work (currently, `MANAGER_ID` is missing).

Comment: I get this error: expression is of wrong type. I guess that's because I didn't add manager_id.

Comment: Yes; you'll have to add MANAGER_ID into cursor's FOR loop.